# Citation for isometric embeddability of $\ell_2$ into $\ell_p^\binom{n}{2}$ for $p \geq 1$?

Tags: reference-request, cg.comp-geom, metric-spaces, embeddings

I need to use the following well-known result in my paper:

> Let $X$ be a set of $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then $(X,\ell_2^d)$ embeds isometrically in $\ell_p^\binom{n}{2}$ for all $p \geq 1$.

What is the best reference to cite for this? I found a result which is nearly identical (but doesn't include the $\binom{n}{2}$ dimension bound) in some [lecture notes](http://www-math.mit.edu/~goemans/18409-2006/lec1.pdf) from Michel Goemans, but I'm (a) unsure if I can cite lecture notes in a scientific publication, and (b) still in need of an $O(n^k)$ bound on the dimension.

Comment: Probably still not optimal, but this appears as Exercise 15.5.5 in Matousek’s “Lectures on Discrete Geometry.”

Comment: @Elliot Gorokhovsky - Perhaps you will find some of the discussion here useful:    https://iuuk.mff.cuni.cz/~koucky/LBCAD/papers/CubeAutomorphism.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This paper by Keith Ball seems to be what you are looking for:

> Ball, Keith. "Isometric embedding in $\ell_p$-spaces." 
>   European Journal of Combinatorics 11.4 (1990): 305-311.

Link to the paper here:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S019566981380131X

Comment: Thanks! This works when combined with the Goemans lecture notes.